# Receive all notifications for some apps in a single app(Android & IOS)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

First of all, I'm not a mobile dev. I would like to know whether it is possible to get notified in a different mobile app when other apps receive notifications in the same mobile? If yes, please give me an overview about that.

Any help is appreciated

P.S:  I'm a web dev so I would be able to understand intercepting http requests

Comment: so, just to clarify your question, would you like to develop an application "A" which should be able to "catch" all notifications that each application installed in the smartphone receives?

Comment: @ddb yes thats what I want

Comment: Each apps have different endpoints and behaviour about how they received the data that trigger the notification, I'm not sure if it has been implemented in the API

Answer (score 5):

At this [link](https://yalantis.com/blog/push-notifications-mechanism-outline-ios-and-android/) you can find a detailed description of how push notification are managed in both Android and iOS systems.

For Android there is a [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) that can be implemented by a class within an Android application that is declared to be

> A service that receives calls from the system when new notifications
>   are posted or removed, or their ranking changed.

So it is what you are looking for.

For the iOS world, as Apple declares at this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)

> the operating system handles the deliver of the notification to your client app
>   so you can't do it in iOS.

I hope I was sufficiently clear :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about iOS but on Android it is possible to intercept all of the incoming notifications by extending [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html).

Make sure to declare service in your manifest file before extending class as it says in documentation.

```
 <service android:name=".NotificationListener"
      android:label="@string/service_name"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
 </intent-filter>
```

After you are done with this, make a class that extends NotificationListenerService and implement methods you need, for example onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn)

EDIT:
I would like to note that this is not the hack as another answers suggest but officially supported way of getting the notifications. Keep in mind that this will only work on API level of 18 and greater.

Answer (score 2):

Apple transfers notifications in a secure way. Also notifications are bound to only one app by encryption.

This means that there is no way to intercept notifications or to get them delivered to another app.

Of what I've seen, Google has a very similar implementation. But as always, Android is less secure and allows you to hack, so who knows; but I would be surprised if it were easy.

Comment: what do you think about the other answer?

Comment: @PremAnand As said, I would be surprised if it were possible. Isn't user1347349 not just explaining how to receive notifications for just that app? Ask him/her.